# VBA function that will look in cell comment that have multiple lines for a specific line

Tags: excel, vba

i have a code that will find if a cell comment have a certain word. However, i want it to look at separate lines. In range("A1:A10") some of the cells have comments and the rest does not, there is some comments that look like this

```
Fruit1: Apple
Fruit2: Orange
Fruit3: Banana
```

and the others look like this

```
Fruit1: Apple / Green apple
Fruit2: Orange 
Fruit3: Banana / Kiwi
```

with my current code, when i search for "Banana", this 2 comments will appear in the immediate window, however, i only want it to return the first comment. The following is my attempt on doing this

```
Sub testlike()
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim fruit As String

    fruit = "Banana" 'Is going to be an input msgbox but for testing purposes, i left it at "Banana"
    Set rng = Range("A1:F10")
    For Each cell In rng
        Set c = cell.Find(fruit, LookIn:=xlComments)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print c.Comment.Text
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I am rather new to vba so i apologize if i seem ignorant . Thanks in advance!

Comment: change `fruit = "Banana"`for `fruit = "Fruit?: Banana"` and add `LookAt:=xlWhole` on the find function. This should do it. the `?` is a wildcard which will tell excel to find any fruit number(0 to 9) and using the `xlWhole` won't find the ones with more text.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, this works for this sample code but, as i am going to change the fruit variable to an input msgbox, how should i approach it so that the user only has to type in the fruit name without the  "Fruit?: "?

Comment: Then it's easier... If the user writes the fruit then `fruit = UserInput & ":" & Fruit`

Comment: Oh! This helps me a lot! thanks for explaining and guiding me to the answer.

Comment: Maybe you can confirm wheather or not your comments in the sample are not 2 but actually 6 comments.

Comment: the comments in the post is 2 different comments not 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub testlike()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim fruit As String

    fruit = "Banana" 'Is going to be an input msgbox but for testing purposes, i left it at "Banana"
    Set rng = Range("A1:F10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
    For Each cell In rng
        arr = Split(cell.Comment.Text, Chr(10))
        For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If arr(x) Like "*: " & fruit Then
                Debug.Print cell.Comment.Text
                Exit For
            End If
        Next x
    Next cell
End Sub
```

This is assuming that:

```
Fruit1: Apple
Fruit2: Orange
Fruit3: Banana
```

Is one comment.... or am I mistaken?

Comment: Ya this works! but can i ask what is the purpose of the second for ?

Comment: That's so we can loop through the array created by `Split`. Also notice `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)` to shorten the loop. But be careful when using on a range without comments as it will error out then.

Comment: Oh, i see, thank you so much for clarifying with me!

Comment: And yes that is 1 comment

Comment: Btw, this will return any cell that contain a substring like `"*: " & fruit` @Vbanoob. If you desire so, you can also stop the second `For` loop.

Comment: Oh, actually i wanted that too, your code perfectly matched what i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the first hit, you can simply exit the for loop after finding it:

```
Sub testlike()
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim fruit As String

    fruit = "Banana" 'Is going to be an input msgbox but for testing purposes, i left it at "Banana"
    Set rng = Range("A1:F10")
    For Each cell In rng
        Set c = cell.Find(fruit, LookIn:=xlComments)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print c.Comment.Text
            Exit for ' <-- this will exit the for loop 
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, but what i want is to look for the word "Banana" only and if there is anything after "Banana" , i want to ignore it, so if the position of the cells is flipped, i still want that comment to be returned.

Comment: Your comment only confused me more. Maybe you should try and clarify your question.

Comment: So sorry if i am confusing you, so lets say the first cell comment is called red and the second cell comment is called orange, and in this post, i placed red before orange, and i only want to return the red's comment. But if i were to place orange before red, i still want to return the red's comment. And if i use the Exit For method, i will get orange in that scenario.

Comment: Please don't comment but instead clarify your question.